# R- crosstable: assign the output to a variable

Tags: r, frequency

I need to assign the output of a cross table to a variable in the same format of he output.

```
table(ops$days_until_1st_payment,ops$costo_real_bin10)
```

I see:

```
print (table)
     0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9   1 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 1.8 1.9   
  -1   3   4   6   2   2   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0           
  0  714 921 267  57 225  19  64  11  56  19  27  27  11  17   6  15   3  11   3             
  1  278 664 292 207 222  33  62   7  38  16  29  22  10  15   4  16   1  10   2            
  2  262 748 334 260 235  60 102  17  53  12  37  21  14  20   3   8   2   8   3
```

But when I save it I get:

a<-table(ops$days_until_1st_payment,ops$costo_real_bin10)

```
View(a)

    Var1    Var2    Freq
1   -1  0   3
2   0   0   714
3   1   0   278
4   2   0   262
5   3   0   148
```

How can I do to save it in the same format that it's printed?

thanks!

Comment: Convert it to a `data.frame` first with `as.data.frame.matrix` and then try.

Comment: Huh, that is kind of weird. Supposedly `View` is designed to display matrices but the illustrated behavior suggests it really coercing to a dataframe with in the case of a table object makes it go to a "long" format.

Comment: @BondedDust, right--I was just about to suggest `View(unclass(a))` when I realized that their problem isn't about saving but about using `View`. The title is very misleading.

Comment: I think it's at the very least unexpected behavior and frankly I consider it a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of the word "save" is a little misleading. I take it you mean "to assign the output to a variable".

Two suggestions would be:

1. Convert the `table` to a `data.frame`:

   ```
   aDF <- as.data.frame.matrix(a)
   ```
2. Remove the `table` attribute from your `table`:

   ```
   aMat <- unclass(a)
   ```

The `View` function should work with either of these.

---

As @BondedDust points out in the comments to the question, this seems to be quite unexpected behavior since `is.matrix(a)` would be `TRUE` and `View` should work with matrices too. `class(unclass(a))` would return `"matrix"`.